# Python Fabric load config from separate file

Tags: python, passwords, fabric

I am use python fabric with all configuration in one .fab file.
How can I put sensitive data as password to separate file and then import/load to fab main file?

Comment: Since fab files are simply Python files you should simply be able to do a normal Python `import` of your separate file into the main file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a simple function within your fabfile.py to read your passwords out of a separate file.  Something along the lines of:

```
def new_getpass(username):
    with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as f:
        for entry in [l.split(":") for l in f.readlines()]:
            if entry[0] == username:
                return entry
    return None
```

This will return `None` in the event that the username cannot be found and the entire user's record as a list in the event the user is found.

Obviously my example is getting its data from `/etc/passwd` but you can easily adapt this basic functionality to your own file:

`credentials.dat`

```
database1|abcd1234
database2|zyxw0987
```

And then the above code modified to use this file like this, with the slight variation to return only the password (since we know the database name):

```
def getpass(database):
    with open("credentials.dat", "r") as f:
        for entry in [l.split("|") for l in f.readlines()]:
            if entry[0] == username:
                return entry[1]
    return None
```

While not as simple as an import, it provides you flexibility to be able to use plaintext files to store your credentials in.

Comment: Yea the plaintext files might not be the best place to store sensitive data but its a good idea for a quick test.

Comment: I would agree that plaintext isn't always the best option, but there are times it is a serviceable solution.  Considering Jaime was originally asking about using import/load I don't think plaintext is out of the realm of usefulness for him.

Comment: Agreed! +1 thoughtful answer.

Comment: Hi zzzirk, 
 Very nice solution! This is what I need!
 The only thing to add is .rstrip() for chomp newline characters from my passwords.
Thank you!